# Using PIL (Python) to find the given value of RGB in jpeg image?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

Now I read a jpeg image using PIL, get the values of RGB.

Although I can combine all the RGBs and then find the width and height that equal to the given value of rgb.

Is there any more effective method or function achieve this goal?

[image: Weather Radar Maps of USA]

My ultimate goal is to get data of [dBZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBZ_(meteorology)) on this image, including latitude and longitude information.

So first step, I need to get coordinates in image equal to the given RGB.

Comment: What do you mean? You have a rgb value, and you want to find matching pixel coordinates in the image?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: @Dashadower yeah, that's my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NumPy's [`argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) is a straightforward way to achieve what you want. For example, you could obtain the spatial coordinates of those pixels with RGB values `[105, 171, 192]` like this:

```
In [118]: from skimage import io

In [119]: import numpy as np

In [120]: img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuHas.png')

In [121]: ref = [105, 171, 192] 

In [122]: indices = np.argwhere(np.all(img == ref, axis=-1))

In [123]: indices
Out[123]: 
array([[ 71, 577],
       [ 79, 376],
       [ 79, 386],
       [ 95, 404]], dtype=int64)
```

The following snippet makes it apparent that the results above are correct:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.imshow(img)
ax1.set_title('Original map')
ax1.set_axis_off()

ax2.imshow(img)
ax2.set_title('Pixels with RGB = ' + str(ref))
for y, x in indices:
    ax2.add_artist(plt.Circle((x, y), 8, color='r'))
```

[image: Pixels highlighted]

Comment: Nice, thanks. So is there any way to get the coordinates in earth from the image?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You need to georeference the image. Have a look at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228489/how-to-convert-image-pixel-to-latitude-and-longitude) to find out how to convert image coordinates into latitude and longitude.

Comment: Sorry. I just solving the coordinates problem and forget mark.-_-